# Using EJS template in package.json name

Tags: node.js, npm, ejs, yarnpkg, package.json

I use EJS for `package.json` `name` in my templates for my "template-generator" cli tool.

`cli --name=new-project --template=react`

I render selected template with EJS and copy it. Problem is if I want to add/remove package in that template I need to rename it to something else because it cointains illegal characters:

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "<%= projectName %>",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "0.0.0"
  }
  ...
}
```

And both yarn and npm returns same error:

```
yarn install v1.22.5
error package.json: Name contains illegal characters
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Is there a workaround or any other package I can use instead of EJS to achive my goal?

Comment: That package.json _is not a valid package.json_, so npm and yarn quite correctly flag it as bad. It's actually a "package.json template", so call it something like `package.json.template` or `package.template` or `package.json.ejs` or anything that isn't the real filename so that npm/yarn don't try to load it in, and then have your tool render that template to a real `package.json` in the dir it needs to build.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yeah I get that. Problem is if I rename `package.json` it won't add packages to `dependencies` when I ran `yarn add package`

Comment: I need to keep name "legal" or trick yarn or npm into thinking it is legal but still be able to add packages and then later use name for template for new package name

Comment: yes of course? You need _two_ files: one `package.json` that is your project's `package.json`, and includes all of your projects dependencies, run scripts, etc. etc. And then you either make a _second_ `package.json.ejs` that is you keep synced but contains ejs templating strings and that you render to new dirs, _or_ you make your CLI copy over the original `package.json`and then as part of the copying step, update the name field with a small node script that loads it, changes it, and then writes it back (because node can load json with `require`). And then you don't need ejs.

Comment: End up doing special treatment for `package.json` (parsing and stringifying back), not sure if it will case a problem because I use 2 spaces while other people may prefer something else (if I ever make this cli public). Not a most elegant way but can't complain - it works. Thanks!

Comment: spaces? You are aware that the `name` field is used for publishing packages to the npm and yarn registries, right? Don't use names that deviate from what they work with.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's TEMPLATE package, of course I wouldn't be publishing it to npm.

Comment: That is the opposite of "of course": there are tons of generator projects on npm, like facebook's `create-react-app`, Express's `express-generator`, etc. etc. that you install globally, so that you can run its command to generate your a project instance. If you're writing a CLI tool to generate new projects, that's literally what those do, too, and most people familiar with the node ecosystem would _fully_ expect you to want to do things the right way because you intend to publish that generator itself to npm, so others can install and use it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry you misunderstood me, I have "template generator project" and in that project there is "templates" folder for example "templates/typescript-electron" and `name` field should be replaced with name user provided through cli